# ggplotly plots negative bars in positive direction

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am using a geom_bar plot in ggplotly, and it renders negative bars positive. Any ideas why this might be the case, and in particular how to solve this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
dat1 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(-13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

# Bar graph, time on x-axis, color fill grouped by sex -- use position_dodge()
g <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
ggplotly(g)
```

Why would the first bar be in a positive direction, with a negative value?

The versions that I am using is the latest:

plotly_3.4.13

ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue for `ggplotly` (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/560)

Comment: Ah I see... Well that is unfortunate. Any suggestions on circumventing this problem without busting open plotly (e.g. by changing some specifications)? Or would it be best to wait for a fix?

Comment: I think that depends on your specific use-case - are you sure you need to use plotly?

Answer (score 3):

If you write your plotly object to another variable you can modify the plotly properties including the 'data' it uses to render the plot.

For your specific example append this to your code:

```
#create plotly object to manipulate
gly<-ggplotly(g)

#confirm existing data structure/values
gly$x$data[[1]]  
# see $y has values of 13.53, 16.81 which corresponds to first groups absolute values  

#assign to original data
gly$x$data[[1]]$y <- dat1$total_bill[grep("Female",dat1$sex)]

#could do for second group too if needed
gly$x$data[[2]]$y <- dat1$total_bill[grep("Male",dat1$sex)]

#to see ggplotly object with changes
gly
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a general solution that works in cases where facet wrap is being used. Here is an example of the problem with toy data:

```
set.seed(45)

df <- data.frame( group=rep(1:4,5), TitleX=rep(1:5,4), TitleY=sample(-5:5,20, replace = TRUE))

h <- ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(TitleX,TitleY),stat = 'identity') + facet_wrap(~group)

h
```

[image: Fake Data with Negatives]

When we use ggplotly we see what OP saw, which is that the negatives have disappeared:

```
gly <- ggplotly(h)
gly
```

[image: Where did the negatives go?]

I wrote a function that will check for the instances in each facet list where the y values in the text are given as 0, which seems to be a comorbid issue with the one I am currently addressing:

```
fix_bar_ly <- function(element,yname){
  tmp <- as.data.frame(element[c("y","text")])
  tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(
    y=ifelse(grepl(paste0(yname,": 0$"),text),
             ifelse(y!=0,-y,y),
             y)
  )
  element$y <- tmp$y
  element
}
```

Now I apply this function to the data for each facet:

```
data.list <- gly$x$data
m <- lapply(data.list,function(x){fix_bar_ly(x,"TitleY")})
gly$x$data <- m
gly
```

[image]

For some reason the spaces between the bars have disappeared ... but at least the values are negative in the appropriate places.